# Understanding decision tree model in SAS Enterprise Miner

Tags: decision-tree

I'm looking to find out a little more about the automated generation of decision trees using SAS Enterprise Miner.

I'm looking to find out what types of decisions were made and basically the meaning of the example decision tree and each of its components.[image: Decision Tree]

If anyone might have some helpful info on this, It would be great to hear it.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Looks like it split the dataset 4 times on [Gift Count 36 Months], [Gift Amount Last], [Time Since Last Gift], and [Gift Amount Average Card 36 Months].  Also looks like you used the same data set for training as validation which is probably meaningless.